# Electron vue new window with child route

Tags: vue.js, electron, router

In electron vue I am suppose to create new vue instance for each new window. This works fine untill I want to load router child component to fresh window. For example I have entry

```
add: path.join(__dirname, '../src/renderer/pages/add.js'),
```

then in pages/add.js I'm creating new vue instance with such routers route:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'add',
        component: require('@/components/add/add').default,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => guard(to, from, next),
        children: [
            {
                path: 'exp',
                component: require('@/components/add/exp').default,
                beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => guard(to, from, next)
            },
```

If i would like to load just `/` it would works fine but my add.vue component is

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

and when I start new window which is suppose to load add.html I want it to load child route from the very beggining:

```
createAddExpPlaceWindow() {
    const winUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? `http://localhost:9080/#/add/exp`
        : `file://${__dirname}/add.html/!#/exp`;
```

and this path `file://${__dirname}/add.html/!#/exp` is incorrect as I see blank window. I tried also `file://${__dirname}/add.html/exp` and `file://${__dirname}/add.html/#/exp` none of them seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix I just changed path to `file://${__dirname}/add.html/exp?opt=exp` and basing on `window.location.search` in add.vue created hook I'm pushing route by `router.push({ path: 'exp' })`.